# Mathematica Error Message Help

Tags: warning-messages

when using NMaximize[], I keep getting the following error message:

[image]

Can someone please explain what <<99>> + <<86>> = 0 means?

Comment: Mathematica has abbreviated its output.  `<<99>>` indicates 99 missing terms.

Comment: Not necessarily missing, but supressed from display, i.e. it says there is a sum of 99+86=185 terms that MMA does not display in its entirety in order to keep the generated message concise.

Comment: See documentation for [`Short`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Short.html)